# AWK how to read this requirement into an array?

Tags: arrays, awk, split

I have a file:

```
AA BB CC DD
BB CC DD AA 
BB CC DDA AA
CC DD AA BB
```

This command prints the line:

```
$ awk '{if($3=="DD") print}' file
BB CC DD AA
```

I want this condition to write to the array. This command does not work:

```
$ awk '{if($3=="DD") split($0, a, RS); print a[1]}' file

BB CC DD AA 
BB CC DD AA 
BB CC DD AA
```

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

I wanted to write to an array of lines from the pattern 'DD'.

These are good solutions:

```
awk '{if($3=="DD") {split($0, a, RS); print a[1];}}' file
awk '$3=="DD"{split($0, a, RS); print a[1];}' file
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's hard to understand what your goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the result regardless of whether `$3 == "DD"`, which seems unlikely to be what you want.

You're also splitting with `RS` which is not set here so for sample output, compare:

```
awk '{if($3=="DD") {split($0, a); print a[1];}}' file
```

which splits with `FS` instead (hence prints just `BB` for the above).

Comment: I wanted to write to an array of lines from the pattern 'DD'.

These are good solutions:

`awk '{if($3=="DD") {split($0, a, RS); print a[1];}}' file`
`awk '$3=="DD"{split($0, a, RS); print a[1];}' file`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely clear on what you want to do, but try this:

```
awk '$3 == "DD" { print $1 }' file
```

The manual splitting you're doing is unneeded in awk.

Comment: I'm guessing the above is trimmed-down from a larger awk script that actually has `RS` set to something, and is supposed to do further processing after `split`-ing, but of course that's not actually in the original question. :-)

Comment: I wanted to write to an array of lines from the pattern 'DD'.

These are good solutions:

`awk '{if($3=="DD") {split($0, a, RS); print a[1];}}' file`
`awk '$3=="DD"{split($0, a, RS); print a[1];}' file`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is the idiomatic way, no doubt